# Setting metric on default route

Tags: linux, redhat, linux-networking

I have a Redhat server with 4 virtual networks. 
 
The problem is when the server is setting up the networks, the IP routes gets the wrong metrics on the default routes.

I have tried creating a file called `route-ens3` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` that looks like

```
192.168.3.1 dev ens3 metric 99
```

But that does not help :(

So how can I setup the metrics on the default ip route? 
Do I have to change the name for the networks, so it comes in the order I want the metrics, as it looks like that is the way it is ordered at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Red Hat are you using?  If it's RHEL 7 or 8 you can use a simple NetworkManager command (or GUI) to set the route metric. Take a look at `man nm-settings` for the "route-metric" value.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
# nmcli connection modify "ens3" route-metric 99
```

https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/nm-settings.html